# mongoose findOneAndModify is it possible to set a value to a variable or a default if undefined $set:{key:value || 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im working on a project for fcc where im using a api to gather stock infomation and then my own database to record likes inside my promise.all i use 2 fetch() one to get stock info one to search my mongoDB to find the stock object with likes recorded and then add 1 like if that person liked and display. however if the stock has not been searched for before im creating a new document and i want to set the likes to a default value as my previous likes are undefined this is what i tried. 
the key part which isnt working is { $set:{"likes":stock.likes+1 || 1}} i was wondering if there was another way i could set the || OR

```
    app.route('/api/like/:stock')
      .get((req,res) => {
  const stockName = req.params.stock.toUpperCase()
  StockLike.findOne({"stock":stockName})
  .then(stock => StockLike.findOneAndUpdate({"stock":stockName},{ $set:{"likes":stock.likes+1 || 1}}, {upsert:true, new:true}))
  .then(nxt => res.json(nxt)) 
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))

      })
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just initialize 'likes' to zero instead of undefined? Your mongo schema should allow for this.

Comment: i didnt know i could set a default value inside the model, doing that and changing the findOne to another upsert findAndUpdate sorted the issue thanks alot!